# MPMediaPickerController panel doesn't let me pre-play the song

Tags: ios, cocoa, media-player, playback, mpmediapickercontroller

When I present the MPMediaPickerController panel I can quite choose a song but I can't pre-play any song. This doesn't help the user to choose the right song. The user can't remember all of his songs from the title. Pre-listening the tune could help a lot. Is any way to make the panel show a play button on each song row?

iOS 16.5, iPhone XR, XCode 14.3 on macOS 13.2

```
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select a song to play";
mediaPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```